# Using streams to apply different functions on key value pair depending on keys

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Currently the code use plain old foreach loop

```
String preEvalObj = new String("123");
for(Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : someHashMap.entrySet()){
  String key = entry.getKey();
  Float value = entry.getValue();
  if(preEvalObj.equals(key)){
    lambda1Onvalue...
  }else{
    lambda2lambda1Onvalue..
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to achieve something like

```
someHashMap.entrySet().stream().apply((key,value) -> if preEvalObj.equals(key) lambda1 else lambda2)
```

Can I use streams to achieve my goal?

Comment: Do lambdas return something? What do you want to do with the mapped values? Put them in a list, map, just consume the values different, as per each key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @nullpointer's answer, if the goal is to alter the values, you can do it like this

```
myHashMap.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
      if (!e.getKey().equals(trigger))
          e.setValue(setNewValue);
      else
          e.setValue(setOtherNewValue);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible way(not using streams though) could be to iterate over the key, value pair (`BiConsumer` implementation) as:

```
someHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
    if (preEvalObj.equals(key)) {
        someOpsOnValue(); // lambda1Onvalue
    } else {
        someOtherOpsOnValue(); // lambda2lambda1Onvalue
    }
});
```

or the same expressed as a little more readable at least IMHO

```
BiConsumer<String, Float> biConsumer = (key, value) -> {
    if (key.equals("123")) { // preEvalObj
       someOpsOnValue(); // lambda1Onvalue
    } else {
       someOtherOpsOnValue(); // lambda2lambda1Onvalue..
    }
};

someHashMap.forEach(biConsumer);
```

*Side note*, the constructor is redundant for `String` initialisation -

```
String preEvalObj = "123";
```

Comment: Exactly, Thanks a lot:)

Comment: But mind the existence of dedicated lookup methods, like `Map.get(…)`, which work way more efficient than iterating over all mappings and calling `equals` on each key.